# Is sdk going to be failure

Tags: javascript, android-studio, sdk

I am a new programmer and I made a new application but I had a problem then error I got from the android studio is please select android SDK and after I select the SDK and add it again I see this problem

``[image]

```
I had confused problem with sdk
```

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the right folder that contains the SDK.

Comment: Apparently your IDE is not recognizing your SDK, try to reinstall it